# ¬ at the end of each line in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

this might be a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer to it. So, how can I add a ¬ to the end of each line of my vim files? It's more about styling, avoid trailing spaces, etc, like this colorscheme: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/solarized-dualmode.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
set list
set listchars+=eol:¬
```

See `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`.

Answer (score 4):

If you type in:

```
:set list
```

then vi should show you the end of each line with a `$` character. Assuming all you want is to capture trailing space, that will do the trick. You can then turn it off with:

```
:set nolist
```

It actually  gives you other things like making tabs visible as well, very handy when trying to track down Python problems with indentation, or things that print differently due to different tab width settings.

Of course, if you're looking to remove white space at line end, you can use regular expressions in your substitute commands:

```
:g/  *$/s///g
```

Comment: thanks, that was what I'm looking for :P
then I just needed to change the symbol to ¬: set listchars=eol:¬

Answer (score 2):

```
:set list listchars+=eol:¬
```

Or if you're just interested in seeing trailing spaces you could use:

```
:set list listchars+=trail:∙
```